# how can I login to phpmyadmin without login to cpanel

Tags: php

is there a way that I can login to phpmyadmin without login in to cpanel?

I have username and password of database but when I want to go to phpmyadmin it says I should login to cPanel first

Answer (score 0):

You can use different application than phpmyadmin, like adminer. This is lightweight.
To use this you have to put it to your root folder and access by using 
your-site-address/adminer.php

https://www.adminer.org/

Comment: that was the weirdest answer I ever get :| I know the direct pma url but it won't pass me through force me to login to cpanel account

Comment: then you can try adminer

Comment: it is possible that server refuse my ip?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I have to run it through xampp or something?

Comment: you have to just upload adminer.php on your site root path and access this by using your-site-address/adminer.php.

if your site root is www.google.com then your path is something like that

 www.google.com/adminer.php

Comment: I ran it on localhost and get the 1045 error (access denied)